# XamDataGrid GroupByEvaluator Date Sorting vb.net

Tags: grouping, infragistics, xamdatagrid, date-sorting

I've been trying to implement some custom grouping with Infragistics xamDataGrid (Infragistics3.Wpf.DataPresenter.v9.1.Express), and pretty much cribbed the entire bit of code from the [Infragistics site](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2011.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v11.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.FieldSettings~GroupByEvaluator.html). I have two different date fields -- Due Date, and Reminder Date -- using GroupByEvaluator. Everything seemed well and good until I tried to add both fields to the GroupByArea.

What happens is this: the nested field groups according to the date of the parent field as opposed to grouping of the parent field. For example, when I drag the "Due Date" (parent) field to the GroupBy, it'll group these records by Due Date into four categories -- Due Next Year, Due This Year, Past Due, and Not Set. Perfect. But when I drag the "Reminder Date" field (nested) to the GroupBy, I'll find multiple labels of the same "Reminder Date" grouping nested under Due Date "Past Due".

I'm a newbie posting to SO, so I can't post an image. Instead, I'll type one out:

- Past Due (Due Date)

  - Not Set (Reminder Date)
  - This Month (Reminder Date)
  - Not Set (Reminder Date)
  - Older (Reminder Date)
  - Not Set (Reminder Date)
  - etc....

With each subsequent nested grouping, the earliest Due Date (value of the parent grouping) is equal to or greater than the greatest Due Date of the previous grouping. It appears as though the "Past Due" collection is sorted by Due Date asc, and it's iterating through each record and creating a new nested group whenever there is a change in the nested label. So after 5 groupByRecords are given the label of "This Month", when the next "Not Set" groupByRecord pops up a new nested label is created instead of continuing to populate the existing one.

I'm having a related issue with sorting, which I suspect is what this entire issue hinges on. If the grid has been sorted according to Due Date, all of the sort by functionality of the other fields are constrained by the Due Dates. For example, sorting by client name will not sort all client name records into ascending or descending. Instead, it will sort, but it sort by Due Date first, and then Name.

Sorry I can't attach an image. Hopefully I explained the issue okay.

Thanks in advance! Code below:

```
 Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
 Imports Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter
 Imports System.Windows
 Imports System.Windows.Controls

 Partial Public Class ManageEntities
 Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.InitializeGroupByGrid()
 End Sub

 #Region "CustomGrouping"
       'http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v12.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.IGroupByEvaluator.html 
Private Sub InitializeGroupByGrid()
    For Each f In Me.SelectorGrid.FieldLayouts(0).Fields
        If f.Name = "Form1DueDate" OrElse f.Name = "Form1LastReminderDate" Then
            f.Settings.GroupByEvaluator = New CustomDateTimeEvaluator

            ' group by the data field
            Dim fsd As FieldSortDescription = New FieldSortDescription()
            fsd.Field = f
            fsd.Direction = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending

            Me.SelectorGrid.FieldLayouts(0).SortedFields.Add(fsd)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
 #End Region

End Class

 #Region "CustomDateTimeEvaluator"

 '//20150918 - From infragistics: http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2013.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v13.1~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.IGroupByEvaluator.html
Friend Class CustomDateTimeEvaluator
Implements IGroupByEvaluator

Private Const NotSet As String = "Not Set"
Private Const PastDue As String = "Past Due"
Private Const DueThisYear As String = "Due This Year"
Private Const DueNextYear As String = "Due Next Year"
Private Const RemindThisMonth As String = "This Month"
Private Const RemindLastMonth As String = "Last Month"
Private Const Older As String = "Older"

Dim targetDate As DateTime = Nothing

Public Function DoesGroupContainRecord(ByVal groupByRecord As GroupByRecord, ByVal record As DataRecord) As Boolean Implements IGroupByEvaluator.DoesGroupContainRecord
    Dim cellValue As Object = record.GetCellValue(groupByRecord.GroupByField)
    Dim desc As String = groupByRecord.Description

    ' handle null values specially
    If cellValue Is Nothing Or TypeOf cellValue Is DBNull Then
        Return desc = NotSet
    End If

    ' if the value is not a date time, just group them together
    If TypeOf cellValue Is DateTime = False Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return desc = GetDateLabel(CType(cellValue, DateTime), groupByRecord.GroupByField.Name)
End Function

Public Function GetGroupByValue(ByVal groupByRecord As GroupByRecord, ByVal record As DataRecord) As Object Implements IGroupByEvaluator.GetGroupByValue
    Dim cellValue As Object = record.GetCellValue(groupByRecord.GroupByField)
    Dim desc As String = String.Empty
    Dim targetDate As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

    If cellValue Is Nothing Or TypeOf cellValue Is DBNull Then
        desc = NotSet
    ElseIf TypeOf cellValue Is DateTime Then
        targetDate = CType(cellValue, DateTime)
        desc = GetDateLabel(targetDate, groupByRecord.GroupByField.Name)
    End If

    groupByRecord.Description = desc
    Return targetDate
End Function

Public ReadOnly Property SortComparer() As System.Collections.IComparer Implements IGroupByEvaluator.SortComparer
    Get
        Return Nothing
    End Get
End Property

Private Function GetDateLabel(ByVal dt As DateTime, ByVal fldName As String) As String
    Dim d As String = NotSet
    Dim comparison As Integer = Nothing
    Dim currentYear As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Now)

    '//If no date, return NotSet
    If dt.Ticks = 0 Then
        Return d
    End If

    '//Group by fieldname name
    If fldName.ToLower = "form1duedate" Then
        '//Past Due includes any records where the Form 1 Due Date is less than July 1st of the current year
        Dim cDDate As New DateTime(currentYear, 7, 1)

        comparison = dt.Date.CompareTo(cDDate.Date)

        If comparison = 0 Then
            d = DueThisYear
        ElseIf comparison < 0 Then
            d = PastDue
        ElseIf comparison > 0 Then
            d = DueNextYear
        Else
            d = NotSet
        End If
    ElseIf fldName.ToLower = "form1lastreminderdate" Then
        Dim currentMonth As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.Month, Now)
        Dim olderThanDate As New DateTime(currentYear, currentMonth - 1, 1)

        If dt.Date.Year = currentYear AndAlso dt.Date.Month = currentMonth Then
            d = RemindThisMonth
        ElseIf dt.Date.Year = currentYear AndAlso dt.Date.Month = currentMonth - 1 Then
            d = RemindLastMonth
        ElseIf dt.Date < olderThanDate Then
            d = Older
        Else
            d = NotSet
        End If
    End If

    Return d
End Function

End Class

#End Region
```